# Can not create answer sdp between ios and android (mediatek)

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, sdp

I am using webRTC to create a phone call between android and ios.

Everything working fine if android device chip support H264 (Snapdragon, Exynos), but on android device using MediaTek, Android side cannot see the answer SDP from iOS client.

Here is my block code of codec

```
final PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
        final DefaultVideoEncoderFactory encoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(eglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true);
        final DefaultVideoDecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(eglBase.getEglBaseContext());
        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().setOptions(options).
                setVideoDecoderFactory(decoderFactory).
                setVideoEncoderFactory(encoderFactory).
                createPeerConnectionFactory();
```

And the offer SDP of Android (MediaTek) has no line `a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000`

```
 a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:100 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
```

Did anyone face this issue before? and does anyone have a suggestion for my issue? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly, WebRTC for Android does not have H264 Software Decoder by default. So on MediaTek devices, WebRTC cannot pick up H264 format. Could you check the SDP offered by iOS client?

Comment: thank you but I do not receive answer SDP of iOS side, this issue may because of iOS side not work with only VP8/VP9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution, the root cause is that WebRTC ObjC SDK will build without software video codecs (VP8/VP9) by default.

And my solution follows this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/WgQPxtnICTQ

Hope this can help anyone who faces this issue.